# Change Background Image on Fly

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked however, not particularly to the effect that I'm trying to accomplish....

I just finished a Javascript course, and wrote a small script for my website.. It uses Gantry Framework and works really well with Mobile Devices.

If you use your phone, and hold your phone horizontal it resizes that page, if you then turn your phone to vertical it resizes the page yet again.

So I wrote this

```
var cWIDTH = window.innerWidth;
if (cWIDTH < 640 ){
    document.getElementById("swapme").style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/backgrounds/top-image2.jpg')";
}
```

However, it wont change on the fly, for example.. if I turn my phone it wont change the background unless I refresh the page.  I have been looking within the files on my site for the Ajax/jQuery/JSON code that seems to react to this change so I could possibly insert a function trigger.

However once the page loads isn't the variable set already until you refresh the page?

How do I get the variable on the fly, and change on the fly as well?

Comment: You should use CSS media queries for this, not Javascript.

Comment: @Niels much easier solution.

Comment: Look at @Nickhar's answer below. Using CSS Media Queries will give better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted, you'd be better off using CSS media queries.
Try something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  #swapme {
    background-image: url('/images/backgrounds/top-image1.jpg');
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #swapme {
    background-image: url('/images/backgrounds/top-image2.jpg');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook that code you wrote to the window.onresize event, and include an else clause for when the window size is switched back.

Having said that, the result is far easier to achieve without JS at all using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

below some example code i used with phonegap to change the layout. It makes use of the media query's of css 3.

```
    /* Ipad landscape mode */
    @media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        article {
            float:left;
            padding-left: 55px;
        }
    }

/* Ipad portrait mode */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    article {
        float: left;
        width: 340px;
        padding-left: 15px; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is and event that detects when the device orientation changes.

```
window.onorientationchange = function(e) {
    switch(e.orientation) {
        case 0:
            //...
            break;
        case -90:
            //...
            break;
        case 90:
            //...
            break;
        default:
            break; 
    }
}
```